# AngularJS controllerAs not binding input controls

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I'm initializing ControllerAs on all my Routes using the UI Router. The issue i'm having is when i click on Edit record, it takes me to another page which also passes the ID from the current page to fetch the record from the service and data bind the html fields.

In my controller class. When i write

```
var vm = this; //DOES NOT DATABIND 

var vm = $scope; // THIS WORKS, FIELDS GET POPULATED.
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. The first line of code should work because i'm using ControllerAs right ?

Can someone please advise.

Thank you

```
//UI ROUTER
.state('dashboard.editUser',
{
    url: '/editUser/:UserId',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/admin/user/editUser.html',
    controller: 'editUserController',
    controllerAs: 'tF',
    ncyBreadcrumb:
        {
            parent: 'dashboard',
            label: 'Edit User'
        },
});


//EDIT CONTROLLER
(function () {

    var injectParams = ['$stateParams', '$state', 'userService'];

    function editUserController($stateParams, $state, userService) {

        var vm = this;

        //load user
        var loadUser = function () {
            var userId = $stateParams.UserId;
            vm.user = null;

            userService.GetUserDetail(userId)
            .success(function (data) {
                vm.user = data;
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                vm.status = 'Error retrieving data! ' + error.message;
            });
        };

        loadUser();
    };

    editUserController.$inject = injectParams;

    angular
        .module('fatApp.userModule')
        .controller('editUserController', editUserController);
}());
```

Comment: Have you actually specified "controllerAs", e.g. `ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm"`, or in the state definition: `controllerAs: "vm"`? Show more of your code so that we won't waste time speculating

Comment: Since you named the controllerAs "tF", all of the variables in your HTML template should be prefixed with the controller name "tF". For example, if the user object had an email address, you would print it with: `{{tF.user.email}}`.  Are you using the controller name in your HTML template?

Comment: Eh, side note: do not name your 'As' with uppercase letters like `tF`. keep it lowercase.

Comment: @SunilD. thankyou, it's now working.

Comment: @Phill can you please tell me the reson why to keep it lowercase ?